# How to convert a big number back to decimals when you divide 1/15000 using a basic simple calculator?

Tags: calculator

This question has always stumped me since using a simple basic calculator over 20 years ago. I'm using the basic calculator on windows or it can be any for that matter.

I input the following into the calculator: 1 / 15000

The output is this: 6.666666666666667e-5

- What is this number format called?
- Why is there an e-5 at the end?
- Why 6.66666?
- And last of all, how do I convert this back to regular decimal places from that output: .00006

Comment: A closely related notation is usually called [Scientific Notation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) In scientific notation one would write the number as $6.66666666667\times 10^{-5}$. Your variant is sometimes called E-notation. It is used on calculators because $e$-$5$ is more compact than $\times 10^{-5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) The number format is called scientific notation. Follow the link left for you in the comments to find out more.

2.) The e-5 at the end indicates that the actual number has the decimal shifted 5 places to left of what is in the display, so 6.6666666667e-5 = 0.000066666666667.

3.) The decimal is shifted so that you can see more significant digits without making the display larger.

4.) My second answer tells you how to do that.

Comment: what if i wanted to do the shifting with the simple calculator?

Comment: Actually the only reason you would want to convert the number is for display purposes, which is easily done by hand. You can also calculate in scientific notation by hand. I am sure there is information about it in the link Andre provided.

Answer (score 0):

**Scientific to decimal**

Converting a number from scientific notation to decimal notation, first remove the x 10n on the end, then shift the decimal separator n digits to the right (positive n) or left (negative n). The number 1.2304×106 would have its decimal separator shifted 6 digits to the right and become 1 230 400, while −4.0321×10−3 would have its decimal separator moved 3 digits to the left and be -0.0040321.

1/ 15000 =  6.666666666666667e-5

6.666666666666667e-5 = .000067

now the question is how do you convert it back to decimal using the simple calculator. sure i can do it with pen and paper.